# How to send a message when a moderator deletes a message?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to have my discord bot send a message when a moderator deletes a message, I've figured out how to make it work when any message is deleted but I don't know how with only mods deleting.

I think it has something to do with "class discord.AuditLogAction" and "message_delete" but I don't know how it works. I've tried reading the API reference but I found it hard to follow and any tutorials as most were made before discord.py 2.0 so don't work anymore.

```
@client.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    if message.channel != "│vent-help" or message.channel != "┗vent-no-reply":
        if message != "<:1984:1051269758164668497>":
            user = str(message.author)
            await message.channel.send(f"{user}'s message was deleted: <:1984:1051269758164668497>")
```

this is what I wrote for if any message is deleted but if someone who wasn't a mod deleted their own message it would do that too.

Comment: Loop through the first few audit log entries (there's multiple examples in the docs), filter by deletion, set `after` to a few seconds before the event got triggered (to be safe) and check who did it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get guild deleted messages using [`discord.Guild.audit_logs`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=audit_logs#discord.Guild.audit_logs) with [`discord.AuditLogAction.message_delete`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=auditlogaction%20message_delete#discord.AuditLogAction.message_delete) as the **action parameter**, 1 for the **limit parameter** so you can get the last deleted message. After that you can check for the deleter if he's the message author or not also you can check for his roles.

**Explanation:**

**Get the last deleted message:**

```
async for deleted_message in message.guild.audit_logs(action=discord.AuditLogAction.message_delete, limit=1)
```

**Check if the deleter is the message autor**

```
deleted_message.user == message.author
```

**Check if the deleter has the mod role**

```
discord.utils.get(deleted_message.user.roles, id=ROLE_ID)
```

**Final source code**

```
@client.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    async for deleted_message in message.guild.audit_logs(action=discord.AuditLogAction.message_delete, limit=1):
        if deleted_message.user == message.author: return
        if not discord.utils.get(deleted_message.user.roles, id=ROLE_ID): return
        # WRITE YOU CODE...
```

Comment: It says "AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'roles' "

Comment: hmm! what is the account type! I mean who deleted the message?

Comment: i deleted the message

Comment: it works well enough anyway as theres no way someone is gonna be able to delete someone else message